# SQL Server Profiler: Templates not showing / missing

Tags: sql-server-2008

When I start SQL Server Profiler, and I click Run, it says "At least one event must be selected." I see that this is due to the Template being "blank" (and there are no other options) and I'm sure there should be a set of defaults here.

Does anyone know why they would have vanished? And how to get them back?

Am Running Sql Server 2008.

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I have managed to resolve the issue, I solved it by following this link's suggestion:

http://www.mattbutton.com/2011/06/01/sql-profiler-templates-missing/

The following comes from the link:

> If you are connecting to a SQL server with the SQL profiler and none
>   of your templates are showing up, compare the versions of the SQL
>   profiler you are running and the version of SQL server that you’re
>   connecting to; there is likely a version mismatch.
>
> If this is the case, what’s likely happening here is that you’re
>   connecting to a SQL 10.50 instance with a SQL 10.0 profiler and the
>   profile templates for 10.50 aren’t present.
>
> In the case of the profiler from SQL 2008 connecting to a SQL 2008 R2
>   instance, copy your 100 profile templates folder (default install is
>   at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Tools\Profiler\Templates\Microsoft SQL Server\100) into a
>   new folder in the same location with the name “1050″ i.e. C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Tools\Profiler\Templates\Microsoft SQL Server\1050.
>
> Then try to reconnect, and you’ll have access to the profile templates
>   and everything will work fine.

Comment: For others, user created templates are added into appdata in the user section, this trick works on getting them to appear too.

Comment: @Richard - bad thing about posting external links - is they can disappear. A answer would be helpful.

Comment: The explanation into http://www.mattbutton.com/2011/06/01/sql-profiler-templates-missing/ works for me! Thanks

Answer (score 10):

This happens when **SQL Server Profiler connects to different versions of SQL Server**.

Although it allows you to save user templates, it does not always list the templates that you've saved.
Search the user folders in the Profiler AppData area to find the template that you just saved:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SQL Profiler\10.0\Templates\Microsoft SQL Server
```

My template was saved to the "1050" folder.

Then check the Profiler templates installation folder.

My installation is **2008R2** and **2008**, so I've got the 2008 Profiler templates in:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Profiler\Templates\Microsoft SQL Server\
```

If there is no folder matching the one in Profiler AppData, e.g., "1050", or the folder is empty, copy the folder to the installation directory.

I now had the following folder:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Profiler\Templates\Microsoft SQL Server\1050
```

Rename the template in this folder to something like "**Dummy.tdf**".

Profiler can now see the user template that you've created!

Answer (score 2):

SQL 2014 profiler templates don't appear when you connect to a SQL 2016 instances. 
 To get SQL 2016 SSMS You can download it at the link [SQL 2016 SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms)

Answer (score 1):

The built-in templates for SQL 2008 should be stored here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Profiler\Templates\Microsoft SQL Server\100\
```

If they are missing, you can just copy them from another server and drop them in that directory.

Comment: Brian, I have this directory and there's 9 templates in there, which are indeed the ones I'm looking for, however I have tried importing them, and they still don't show up.

Comment: Are you sure that you are running the 2008 version of Profiler (instead of the 2005 version). Make sure you run Profiler.exe and not profiler90.exe. The latter is the SQL2005 version of profiler. The 2005 version won't recognize the 2008 templates.

Comment: Brian, thanks, with your help about the versions I managed to find the correct answer. It is indeed a version thing, however between 2008 and 2008 R2. I've posted the answer. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on "New Trace" in Profiler you will have the ability to select the template you desire.  "Blank" is just one of them (i.e. no actual events).  There is a list that you can select from.

But if you don't want to use a template or you want to add/remove events/columns from the currently selected, there is a tab on the new trace window for you to select what events and info you want to see.

Comment: Sorry, I've just edited my post. There is only "Blank" in the Templates drop down, hence I'm wondering where the others have gone. I realize I can add the events myself, but there was always a set of default template I always used.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create your custom templates, you should place them in the same folder:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Profiler\Templates\Microsoft SQL Server\1050

If you don't see them after that, try scrolling the list box with the name of the templates up and down. In my case, only the default templates were visible and I hadn't noticed the vertical scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

Reason is Mismatch of SQL Server version and Profiler Version (Simply you can check by search in searcher by 'SQL Server Profiler' and check the version and check SQLversion also)

I solved by uninstall existing SSMS and re install the latest in
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms

now working fine

Answer (score -1):

This is what I had to do to find my missing templates:

To save the template: 
File - Save As - Trace Template - "Template Name" .

To open up the template:
File - New Trace - Connect - In "Use the template", pick the template I had saved.